# Render a Win32 widget in the OpenGL context

Tags: winapi, opengl, widget

Is it possible to intercept a control's paint event and make it draw in the opengl context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Qt there's a [fun demo](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2008/12/02/widgets-enter-the-third-dimension-wolfenqt/) showing (working) Qt widgets rendering 3D in an OpenGL context.  How useful that is to you depends how how hooked you are on the native win32 controls specifically.

Comment: QT is nice but is paid at the end. The open widgets for opengl I saw, I didnt like much. I was thinking in some direct hook on the win api so I found that WM_PRINT can in someway support it but not for all kinds of controls from what I read. Anyway, WM_PRINT uses a hDC (and I dont know exactly how to mix it with the hRC).

Comment: Have you considered using Direct3D instead of OpenGL ?  There's a IDirect3DSurface9::GetDC method which will get you a HDC for a render surface (or at least these was in DirectX9; I believe it may be deprecated or even missing completely in DirectX10).

Comment: I just came across it:
http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/licensing
Qt has a LGPL license, so if I use it without modifications my code can remain closed. Looks good.

Comment: Ah sorry!  I could have told you that but I didn't understand what you meant by "paid at the end".  Have fun using Qt; it's truly great.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this is possible, but this tends to writing your own gui.

It whould be simpler to use a complete openGl Gui library.

http://libufo.sourceforge.net/